# codenameone Cant Open Designer or Settings

Tags: settings, codenameone, designer

I've a new computer with Debian 9 / 64bits.

After installing Netbeans 8.2 and Codename Plugin 5.0 if i try to open "CodenameOne Settings" or "CodenameOne Designer" nothing happens.
I've checked JRE_JAVA and JDK_JAVA and PATH environment variables and them points to the correct path.
I don't see any error message but the tools dont start.

I dont know what happens but i remember a similar issue in the old computer with Debian 6 / 32bits.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot
Ramon Garcia

Answer (score 0):

The default version of Java on Linux systems is OpenJDK which is a bit problematic due to its lack of JavaFX support. With newer JDKs we updated Codename One to download JavaFX dynamically as it was removed from the JDK but since the dynamic download only works with JDK 10 or newer (due to the way the people at Oracle compiled JavaFX) this would be the minimum version of OpenJDK.

So you can either install Oracle JDK 8 or Open JDK 11 to keep compatibility.

Notice you can track this issue by running the designer/gui builder from the command line and seeing the point of failure: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html